# Count in Query not returning anything

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

When I use the syntax:

```
=query(Clients!A:J,"select H where (H='Yes')",-1)
```

I only get "Assigned" as a result, no # of records.

[image: WA108688 example]

Answer (score 0):

```
    =query(Clients!A:J,"select H where H contains 'Yes'",-1)
```

More of a syntax error. `=` checks whether it is exactly equal and might contain errors. `contains` should do the trick.